# How to measure the sizes of files inside an open .xlsx file

Tags: excel, zip

Can anyone help with the following :

How to measure the sizes of the different files inside an `.xlsx` file while it is open for write in my excel?

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow! To get good answers around here, it is always best to give all relevant information. Information like: Do you want to get the sizes from within excel or by some other application, do you want to use VBA, or whatever else you want to do. The lack of this information probably caused the downvote your question got.

Answer (score 0):

As you already noted with your [zip] tag, `.xlsx` is actually a zip file. Therefore, even if the file is opened you still access it read-only and get the information you want.

I usually use the great [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/download.htm) (the shareware is fully functional): navigate to the file and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>ArrowUp</kbd> and in the opposite window a new tab will open. In this tab, you can browse the `.xlsx` (or any other MS Office ZIP for that matter) as a normal folder, i.e. seeing it contents/file sizes/etc.

Comment: @SeanCheshire: Can it also open files that are not named `.zip`?

Comment: yes. I have used it to actually edit xlsx files (pressing *F4* on the appropriate sub-file within the xlsx file)

Comment: great! Funnily, F4 is the same shortcut in TotalCmd! ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i need to do it programatically, i'm trying to write an add-in that will display the workbook components along with thier sizes